# Групповое присвоение значений в Lua

Tags: скрипт, lua

Запускаю программу и пишет

```
'=' expected near 'while'
```

Код программы

```
local menu = none, admin exit,  finc
while true do
io.write("> ")
err, finc = pcall(io.read)
elseif finc == admin then
break
end
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

форма

```
переменная1, переменная2 = значение1, значение2
```

используется в lua для ["группового" присвоения значений](http://www.lua.org/pil/4.1.html):

`переменная1` получит `значение1`, `переменная2` — `значение2`.

я подозреваю, что этой строкой:

```
local menu = none, admin exit,  finc
```

вы хотели присвоить переменной `menu` строку `"none"`, переменной `admin` — строку `"exit"`, а `finc` просто объявить как локальную. тогда надо было сделать примерно так:

```
local menu, admin = "none", "exit"
local finc
```